# Why doesn't zero-width match regex work?

Tags: regex, perl, mainframe, jcl

I wrote a Perl function to replace job name in JCL script. Zero-width match was used here.

```
sub modify_jcl_jobname ()
{
    my ($jcl, $old, $new) = @_;

    $jcl =~ s/
         # The name must begin in column 3.
         ^(?<=\/\/)     

         # The first charater must be alphabetic or national.
        ($old)

         # The name must be followed by at leat on blank.
         # Append JCL keyword JOB 
        (?=\s+JOB)
       /$new/xmig; # Multi-lines, ignore case.

    return $jcl;
}
```

But this function didn't work until I did a simple modification that just deleted the leading sign "^".

```
  #before  ^(?<=\/\/) 

  #after    (?<=\/\/)
```

So I'd like to make it clear that the cause of problem. Any reply would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The problem lies with

```
^(?<=\/\/)
```

That pattern will only match if the spot after which `^` matched is preceded by the two characters `//`. That's never going to happen since `/^/m` matches the start of the string and after a newline.

But you don't want to start matching at the start of the line. You want to start matching 2 characters in. What you want is actually:

```
(?<=^\/\/)
```

After doing some improvements, the code looks like:

```
sub modify_jcl_jobname {
    my ($jcl, $old, $new) = @_;
    $jcl =~ s{
         (?<= ^// )
         \Q$old\E
         (?= \s+ JOB )
    }{$new}xmig;

    return $jcl;
}
```

Improvements:

- Removed the incorrect prototype (`()`). It forced the caller to tell Perl to ignore the prototype (by using `&`).
- Added code (`\Q...\E`) to convert the contents of `$old` into a regex pattern before using it as such.
- Removed the needless capture (`(...)`).
- Switched the delimiters of the substitution (from `s///` to `s{}{}`) to require less escaping.
- Removed highly redundant comments. (Good comments explain *why* something is being done rather than *what* is being done.)

---

The optimiser might handle this version better:

```
$jcl =~ s{
     ^// \K
     \Q$old\E
     (?= \s+ JOB )
}{$new}xmig;
```

Comment: Added alternate solution (using `\K` instead of lookbehind).

Comment: thanks for your complete answer. Accepted all except to remove redundant comments. I think sometimes we need to tell others what is being done especially while writing program using low level language like assembler or languages that have more than one way to do one things typically like Perl.

Answer (score 3):

The `^` sign matches the beginning of the line. You then want something preceded by two slashes - where should these slashes go if the next character is the very first character of the line?

```
s{^//
  ($old)
  ...
 }{//$new}xmig
```

should work: you need no look behind.

**Update:** Thanks to ikegami, I now see why you used it. You want to keep the `//` in the string: well, you can repeat them in the substitution, or move the `^` character into the look-behind.